# CKEditor's not working with EasyAdmin 3 on Symfony 4.4

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, easyadmin

I'm actually working on a project who needs a WYSIWYG interface with Symfony 4.4 and EasyAdmin 3.

I've tried to install FOS_CKEditor by following this doc https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/ivoryckeditorbundle.html and some others tutorials that i've found on Google or Youtube, but unfortunatly I can't figure out why the CKEditorField does not display on my admin dashboard. I think i've been missing something.

Some help would be appreciate, here's my configs files :

Fos_ckeditor:

```
#config/packages/fos_ckeditor.yaml

twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'

fos_ck_editor:
    configs:
        basic_conf:
            toolbar: full
```

EasyAdmin :

```
#config/packages/easy_admin.yaml

easy_admin:
    design:
        form_theme:
            - "@EasyAdmin/form/bootstrap_4.html.twig"
            - "@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig"
```

I've also tried to define the FieldType in the CrudController by adding this :

```
#CrudController

 public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        ..//
        TextareaField::new('corps', 'Corps')
        ->setFormType(CKEditorType::class),
```

But it didn't worked.

Thanks by advance for your help !

Comment: Hello, same issue for me. I'm using EasyAdmin 3 with Symfony 5.1. There is no documentation right now to create a WYSIWYG on EasyAdmin 3

Comment: Hi, I'm still looking for a way to make this work, if I find it I'll let you know
For now I'm using the "TextEditorField" provide by TrixEditor, but it's a bit poor in terms of functionality

Answer (score 8):

According to https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/3412
you can add

```
public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
{
    return $crud
        ->addFormTheme('@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig')
    ;
}
```

It worked fine for me :)

Comment: You saved my life bro! I was starting to fall into depression with this issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the `fos_ck_editor` part like this :

```
fos_ck_editor:
    input_sync: true
    default_config: base_config
    configs:
        base_config:
            toolbar: full
```

Comment: Still not working
I had an other answer telling me that CKEditor wasnt working with EasyAdmin 3, so I don't know if i'm not wasting my time & yours 
Thanks for your help, anyway

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having trouble with this, after adding the line from Bouffe's comment make sure you have the assets installed with commands:

```
bin/console ckeditor:install
bin/console assets:install public
```

This worked for me on EasyAdminBundle 3 and Symfony 5 with FOSCKEditorBundle 2.